# Creating a SSH key with ssh-keygen does not create the .ssh folder

Tags: git, ssh, mingw, version-control, unfuddle

I am trying to create my public/private rsa key pair with msysgit

I run this command:

```
ssh-keygen -C "email@email.com" -t rsa
```

Everything looks fine, I have the message

```
Enter file in which to save the key (/c/Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa)
```

Then I have the confirmation:

```
Your public key has been saved in project.pub
```

But I can't access the folder! It does not exist, it is not even an hidden folder. I don't understand why it does not generate. I am using Windows 7 Ultimate.

Comment: more than that. If you create folder - keys not appears after successful generating. Has you resolved you problem? Stuck the same now

Comment: If you enter `project` as your file, this file gets created in your current directory. If you want it inside the .ssh folder, either `cd` inside or enter the full path.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can start with creating the expected folder, and check you can access it:

```bash
mkdir "%USERPROFILE%\.ssh"
dir "%USERPROFILE%\.ssh"
cd "%USERPROFILE%\.ssh"
```

Make sure you do not have a Windows environment variable named `HOME`, which would take precedence when using `ssh.exe` or `ssh-keygen.exe` commands from a CMD session (as opposed to a bash session).

```bash
echo HOME='%HOME%'
```

You can use (from CMD or bash)

```
ssh-keygen -C "vonc@xxxx" -t rsa -P "" -f ~/.ssh/mykey
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That will create a `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\mykey` and `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\mykey.pub`.

---

As a test, I just created my key without any problem (Seven Ultimate 64bits, msysgit 1.6.5.1.1367.gcd48)

```
$ ssh-keygen -C "vonc@xxxx" -t rsa
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/c/Users/VonC/.ssh/id_rsa):# just press enter
                                                                # to accept the
                                                                # default location
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):                     
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /c/Users/VonC/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /c/Users/VonC/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
xx:yy:zz:aa:bb:cc:... vonc@xxxx
```

With the result:

```
VonC@P ~/.ssh
$ ls -alrt
total 10
-rw-r--r--    1 VonC Administ      642 May 23 21:47 known_hosts
drwxr-xr-x   43 VonC Administ    16384 Jun 15 17:01 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 VonC Administ      398 Jun 19 16:14 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--    1 VonC Administ     1675 Jun 19 16:14 id_rsa
drwxr-xr-x    2 VonC Administ        0 Jun 19 16:14 .
```

Could you check in your bash session (so not CMD) what value your `$HOME` environment variable is set?

```
VonC@P ~/.ssh
$ env|grep HOME
HOMEPATH=\Users\VonC
HOME=/c/Users/VonC     # <=== this must be correctly set
HOMEDRIVE=C:
```

Comment: Thanks VonC, you made me realized that my error was that I was typing a name when I was asked to enter file in which to save the key. I just hitted Enter and it generated id_rsa and id_rsa.pub files.

Now it works perfectly

Comment: @couellet: thank you for this feedback. I have edited my answer to reflect it.

Comment: Check if the .ssh is not a symlink (Mackup and others do this for backups).

Answer (score 40):

I had the same problem and I realized I was trying to enter a file name when it asks for the following "Enter file in which to save the key (c/users/user.name/.ssh/id_rsa)"

Rather just enter nothing and press Enter key to use the default and you will move on.

Comment: I realized it requires full path, not just a name, otherwise file will be created at the cmd current working directory. Moreover if you type name only, you will see in summary default path "bla bla saved in /c/Users/{UserName}/.ssh/id_rsa_name"

Comment: @CeH9 - FWIW, when I made the mistake of typing name only, it *did not* give the full path; it just said ".. saved in myfilename." [If I hit enter to accept the default path, *then* it has the full path to that default location.]

Comment: didn't work for me until I generated it with no file name specified

Answer (score 9):

I faced a similar issue while creating a SSH key and I resolved it this way.

When you use `ssh-keygen -t rsa` to generate a SSH key and it prompts you to

`Enter file in which to save the key (/Users/iamarasekera/.ssh/id_rsa):`

> Do not  give any file name. Instead, just press "Enter" key and go ahead.

Then it will create `.ssh` folder and inside that folder it will generate the 2 files `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`.

You will also see the message `Created directory '/<path to your current folder>/.ssh'.` on your command prompt.

Next, it will prompt you to`Enter passphrase`and you better not skip it.

Check this out for your reference.

[image]

`Note`: If you enter a file name when it prompts you to enter a file name to save the key it creates 2 file as `<filename>` and `<filename>.pub` inside the directory where you are currently located without creating a .ssh folder.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i was wondering why it was not creating anything lol. this explains , thnks

Comment: `inside the directory where you are currently located without creating a .ssh folder.` is the magic phrase here

Answer (score 9):

If you already have a key called "id_rsa" and you want to save a new one in a different name, you need to provide the whole path, if I understood it. So when it asks:

```
Enter file in which to save the key (/c/Users/myname/.ssh/id_rsa):
```

You can type `/c/Users/myname/.ssh/new_key`
and it will be created (I just tested).

Answer (score 6):

I faced similar situation, Solution that worked for me has been described below.

When following message comes while creating the key -

`Enter file in which to save the key (C:\Users\aditya/.ssh/id_rsa):`

Just Press Enter Here , do not provide any filename else the key will get created in your Present Working Directory.

Answer (score 1):

The filename alone is not enough!

you need to specify **full path**. For your requirement

`/c/Users/user/.ssh/project`

Otherwise, your keys will be stored in the **current directory** of the command prompt.

For example, if you were running from `/c/project` your keys will be stored `/c/project/project` and `/c/project/project.pub`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.. Refer link below

http://ekawas.blogspot.co.uk/2007/03/solving-pesky-ssh-issues-in-cygwin.html

edit the passwd file in c:/cygwin64/etc. Open it with wordpad

edit home/YOUR_NAME  to    /cygdrive/c/Documents and Settings/YOUR_NAME

Answer (score 0):

This is late but I after the solutions provided here didn't make a change, I simply ran Git Bash as administrator. It worked as expected this way.