# Error of setup public key for gitolite on ubuntu 12.04 server

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh, gitolite

We follow the post (http://www.bigfastblog.com/gitolite-installation-step-by-step) to install gitolite on ubuntu 12.04 server. When doing /home/git/bin/gitolite setup -pk west_org_selfgen.pub, there is an error:

```
$/home/git/bin/gitolite setup -pk west_org_selfgen.pub
FATAL: errors found but logfile could not be created
FATAL: /home/git/.gitolite/logs/gitolite-2013-09.log: No such file or directory
FATAL: die      'west_org_selfgen.pub' not a readable file
```

There are multiple lines in our public key (west_org_selfgen.pub). We did online search and did not find anyone complaining about this kind of error. Was anyone having the problem before? And how to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you follow [gitolite ssh guide](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/glssh.html)

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f west_org_selfgen
```

That should create the correct pari of keys, with the public one being written in one long line. See for instance "[Creating a SSH key with ssh-keygen does not create the .ssh folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3076214/6309)".

I prefer [starting without a passphrase for test](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10892931/6309):

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f "${H}/.ssh/myKey" -C "Gitolite Admin access (not interactive)" -q -P ""
```