# Configuring GitBash on Windows 7: ssh failing, I'm trying everything, going nuts

Tags: windows, git, ssh

I'm going nuts just trying to ssh to github.

I'm on windows 7.

Honest to Murgatroyd I've been scanning google and forums all day about this without breaking through.

In my latest attempt I've put a config file in C:\Users\myname.ssh. The results are a bit closer to happiness but still not there.

my config simply says:

```
Host github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

The command `ssh -vT git@github.com`  produces:

```
OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/myname/.ssh/config
debug1: Applying options for github.com
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.252.130] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/myname/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1+github5
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1+github5 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.6
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/myname/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /c/Users/myname/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

The top of the output looks like my key is being found and used, and the bottom like it isn't.

I'm pretty baffled.

ANY advice would be deeply appreciated.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

As I mention in "[SSH error on push to an existing project Permission denied (publickey)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20596571/6309)", double-check:

- your `%HOME%` environment variable (should be set to `%USERPROFILE%`)
- your full (Windows) path in your `%HOME%\.ssh\config` file ('`~`' doesn't mean much for Windows).
  For instance:

  ```
  Host gitlab.com
    HostName gitlab.com
    IdentityFile C:\path\to\.ssh\gitlab_rsa
    IdentitiesOnly yes
  ```

Note that you don't need a config file if you are using the default names `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` for your private and public keys.

Comment: Thanks much for your reply. I've added a HOME enviroment var and it's set correctly. And I've put the full path into the config file (which now looks like your example). I am now playing with different ways of writing the path, like c:\etc..., /c/etc..., and so on. But with no change in results, the last few lines of the output keep coming out the same. Do you know of something else I could check?

Comment: @user24477 simply make sure that your public ssh key is registered in your GitHub account,as one line.

Answer (score 0):

I'm kind of guessing here what can possibly go wrong in your case, but among other things to look at, try checking the file mode for the private key and the public key files. It normally should be 600 for a private key (so, only writeable and readable by a file owner, hopefully you - point to check as well), and 644 for a public key file (same, plus readable by all others):

```
$ ll ~/.ssh
-rw------- 1 YOU   YOU   1.8K Sep  5 23:53 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 YOU   YOU    398 Sep  5 23:53 id_rsa.pub
```

If not, try following from a Git Bash:

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
chmod 644 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

As you're on Windows, these commands may have a chance to fail when executed from a Git Bash - because when running it, curiously enough, you don't have enough premissions to modify the file mode (yet). If this is the case, try modifying file access permissions via a standard "File Properties" menu first, and set them to allow "Full Control" by all users. Once done - try modifying file mode again from a Git Bash - should work now. Alternatively you can try running Git Bash as an Administrator, but I never tried this and not sure of the final result.

Speaking of access permissions, final resort is to also double-check the permissions and the owner for a `~/.ssh` directory :)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out -- very weirdly -- that ssh-keygen, under Windows 7, does NOT generate good usable key pairs every time.

I repeated the generate-upload-then-test cycle a few times -- out of sheer desperation -- and the problem simply went away by itself.

Very weird.

Comment: Weird indeed. I never experiences "wrong" key generation on Windows. I stand by my [initial answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20791214/6309). I usually generate my ssh key (without passphrase protection) like in the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19022711/6309).

Comment: I am simply stating the facts. In point of fact, your initial suggestions, while sensible, made no difference. Only several repetitions of generating and trying new key pairs did the trick. But don't let the facts bother you :-)