# How to clone a git repository which is present on a remote linux server into windows

Tags: linux, git

I have a git repository setup on a remote server XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX and want to clone the same in my windows environment. It's actually a webapp present under `/var/www/html/Testsite`. The git repo is created inside the `Testsite` folder.

I was hoping the command:

`git clone http://XXX.XX.XX.XX/Testsite/mysite.git` would work fine but it does not. Please let me know how I can get the URL to configure and clone it into my environment.

However, with the local folder, I am easily able to clone the repository which works totally fine.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the error you get when you try to clone it? Also, can you ping the remote server?

Comment: i get a repository not found error. Its exactly : repository 'http://XX.XX.XX.XX/Testsite/mysite.git' not found error.And yes definitely i can ping the server. I am guessing the URL is not correct.

Comment: yes, there's something wrong with the URL then.

Comment: yes I am able to ping the server.

Comment: Since it's a linux server, try using ssh: git clone ssh://XX.XX.XX.XX/Testsite/mysite.git

Comment: Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: It gives a prompt 'Cloning into mysite' and ask for password. But I have not set any password for it. The linux root password doesnot work . Any idea ? ..

Comment: Can you try doing a git clone ssh://<linux_username>@XX.XX.XX.XX/Testsite/mysite.git

Comment: mysite.git doesnot appear to be a git repository. Thats the error msg that i receive.

Comment: works perfectly fine now. Although I need to provide password at the prompt while cloning it. However I am guessing I can configure the password like directed by VonC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, without configuring your Apache in order to server git request.

The fact that your `mysite.git` is within `Testsite` doesn't make it accessible to git.

As shown in [this config](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/2801e9f5366185b532300fe07e434b60a5cea030/apache/env.conf.tpl#L151-L165), you can define in a separate VirtualHost (so in a separate port, since you are already using port 80/443 on `Testing`) a config in order to call the git script able to interpret a git clone request:

```
ScriptAlias /hgit/ /path/to/git/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend/
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_BACKEND "/path/to/git/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend"
<Location /hgit>
   ...
</Location>
```

---

As for ssh, the right url would be:

```
git clone ssh://account@XX.XX.XX.XX/var/www/html/Testsite/mysite.git
```

And it would work only if you [generate a public and private (non-passhrase protected at first)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3076214/6309), and publish the public key in the `~account/.ssh/authorized_keys`.
Or the sshd (ssh daemon) on the server won't recognize you (hence the password request), and won't know where "`Testing/`" is.